# Prove that $2\mid x$ and $5\mid x$ if and only if $10\mid x$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, divisibility

I have to do it without using Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Can someone check my work?

Prove if $2\mid x$ and $5\mid x$, then $10\mid x$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $2\mid x$ and $5\mid x$. Then, by definition of divisibility, there exists integers $m,n$ such that $2m = x = 5n$. Therefore $5\mid 2m$. Since the $\gcd(2,5) = 1$ it follows that $5\mid m$. Therefore there exists an integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $5k = m$.

---

Prove if $10\mid x$, then $2\mid x$ and $5\mid x$.

Suppose $10\mid x$, then there exists an integer $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $10a = x$. From here it follows that $2 \cdot 5 \cdot a = x$.

I really don't feel like this encompasses the entire proof. Should I be using Euclid's Lemma instead?

Comment: You are missing the punchlines at the end of each section of the proof.  Once you know $5k=m$ that implies $x=10m$ and therefore $10\mid x$.  The final line in each part of the proof should be your conclusion.  Don't stop too soon (even if it is obvious).

Comment: The only thing that looks problematic to me is "Since the $\gcd(2,5)=1$ it follows that $5∣m$." This is certainly true, but do you know it without using the FTA? I don't know what you've learned about this.

Comment: This is my second time taking the class, so I've certainly learned about the FTA, but my professor explicitly requested that we prove the statement without using it. So I'm having a little trouble separating what I'm currently learning from the (admittedly small) amount of information I already know.

Comment: @PaulSinclair this just requires the fact that if $ p$ is prime and $p\mid ab$ then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ which follows from Bezout's theorem and is used to prove FTA.

Comment: @Molly this proof definitely works and doesn't use the FTA. You should be explicit with which theorem you are using with your statement that "it follows that $5\mid m$, just that you can be sure that you're not implicitly using the FTA.

Comment: As I said, it is definitely true. I just wasn't sure if she is allowed to use it. That would depend on what has already been presented in her course.